# Python multiplication inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm trying to implement some mathematical structures in python. A base class from which many others will be inherited is a matrix class. For this class, there is a multiplication implemented:

```
def __mul__(self, other):

    if isinstance(other,matrix):
        if not self._type._ncols == other._type._nrows:
            raise ValueError('Cannot multiply matrix of type "{0}" with matrix of type "{1}"'.format(self._type, other._type))
        arr=[[sum([val1*val2 for val1,val2 in zip(row,col)]) for col in other.columns()] for row in self._array]
        self._type=matrix_type(array=arr)
        self._array=arr
        return self
    else:
        arr = [[val*other for val in row] for row in self._array ]
        self._type=matrix_type(array=arr)
        self._array=arr
        return self
```

This works fine but if I multiply two instances of a class (with the name 'spinor') that inherits from the matrix class, the result is an instance of the matrix class and not of the derived spinor class. This is a problem because the spinor class has some additional functionalities that I need after multiplication.

Is there a way to implement the multiplication is such a way that the return type is reflects the type of the derived classes?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `else` block has two lines that say `self._array = ...`. Is that intentional, or should the first one be `self._type`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. The code you show multiplies a matrix in place, which would be more appropriate for an `__imul__` method than for `__mul__` (which should leave the arguments unmodified). It will always return the left-hand operand, so it should preserve that object's type. When you say that the "type" becomes a matrix, do you just mean the `_type` attribute is being changed inappropriately?

Comment: @Blckknght :The _type attribute is set correctly, but the multiplication method above always returns an instance of the matrix class, even if the object that is being multiplied is an instance of a derived class!

Comment: @user2255204: You'll need to show more code then. The `__mul__` method you've shown will always return the object on the left-hand side, so it will never change that object's type. Getting mathematical operations to work correctly with inheritance can be very tricky. You need to define type coercion rules and make sure all your types follow them in all their operations. Some types may not be interoperable. For instance, if you have two separate subclasses of a `Matrix` type, what type do you get when you multiply them together? It may be more appropriate to raise an exception in such a case.

Comment: @user2255204 `return self` Are you expecting an object to change its own type?